# how to add double notification icons?

Tags: android, notifications

I tried using below code which adds only one image in the notification bar and sets smallIcon image in status bar

```
notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.badge);   //foreground png image
notification.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ic_launcher_background)); // background png image(red)
```

[image]

Please refer the above image, i would like to know how to set the second image in the notifications.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jbimmb Please Look at this screenshot

Comment: You need to set both `.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)`
    And `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)`

Comment: Thanks, but im little new to android. When i try implementing, it says cannot resolve symbol  [link](http://prntscr.com/jbitic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`setLargeIcon(Bitmap bitmap)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLargeIcon(android.graphics.Bitmap)) by definition accept `Bitmap` or an overloaded implementation `setLargeIcon (Icon icon)` accept instance of `Icon`.

> Notification.Builder setLargeIcon (Bitmap b)

Set large icon as follows.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Hi")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0 , notificationBuilder.build());
```

For App tagetting Android O . `NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context)` has been deprecated. You have to use the constructor which has the channelId parameter see [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#NotificationCompat.Builder(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)):

> NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context, String channelId)

Comment: This totally works,absolutely solved my problem. Thanks.